# Rewrite 2 sections of URL for HTACCESS file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to convert a url like this
`url/2013/08/a-very-long-description/`

to something like this
`url/page?name=a-very-long-description`

this is what i've tried thus far and fail
`RewriteRule ^2013/08\/(.*) url/page?name=$1 [L,R=301]`

this is the result I get is
`url/page?name=a-very-long-description/.php`

which if i could remove the `/.php` would work, but cant seem to wrap my head around it

other speculations in the htaccess file:

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another rule that is tacking on the .php to the end. You need to make sure this rule is *before* that one. And change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^2013/08\/([^/]+) url/page?name=$1 [L,R=301]
```